# Strange git file created during stashing

Tags: git, git-stash

Recently after stashing changes in git, I noticed a strange file named "s" in the root directory of my project. It looks like some kind of corrupted git diff.

What might have caused this? How can I prevent it from occurring again?

```
[1mdiff --git a/app/assets/stylesheets/<redacted>/_blog.scss b/app/assets/stylesheets/<redacted>/_blog.scss[m
[1mindex e2b54f0..a7363a1 100644[m
[1m--- a/app/assets/stylesheets/<redacted>/_blog.scss[m
[1m+++ b/app/assets/stylesheets/<redacted>/_blog.scss[m
[36m@@ -3,8 +3,9 @@[m
 $login-gray: #3f3a3c;[m
 $contact-us-blue: #0087fc;[m
 $blog-background-gray: #f2f2f2;[m
[32m+[m[32m$blog-navbar-color: #343434;[m
 [m
[31m-// Header layout[m
[32m+[m[32m// Site header layout[m
 [m
 $blog-navbar-height: 64px;[m
 [m
[36m@@ -35,7 +36,7 @@[m [m$blog-navbar-height: 64px;[m
   }[m
 }[m
 [m
[31m-// Header elements[m
[32m+[m[32m// Site header elements[m
 [m
 .login {[m
   background-color: $login-gray;[m
[36m@@ -47,6 +48,12 @@[m [m$blog-navbar-height: 64px;[m
   background-color: $contact-us-blue;[m
 }[m
 [m
[32m+[m[32m// Blog header[m
[32m+[m
[32m+[m[32m#blog-navbar {[m
[32m+[m[32m  background-color: $blog-navbar-color;[m
[32m+[m[32m}[m
[32m+[m
 // Trapezoids[m
 [m
 .trapezoid {[m
[1mdiff --git a/app/views/blog/posts/index.html.haml b/app/views/blog/posts/index.html.haml[m
[1mindex 1f2d61c..1e9517d 100644[m
[1m--- a/app/views/blog/posts/index.html.haml[m
[1m+++ b/app/views/blog/posts/index.html.haml[m
[36m@@ -21,7 +21,16 @@[m
           %li[m
             %a.contact-us.trapezoid.bottom-left-trapezoid{ href: "#contact" }[m
               Contact Us![m
[31m-  #blog-navbar[m
[32m+[m[32m  %nav#blog-navbar.navbar[m
[32m+[m[32m    .navbar-header[m
[32m+[m[32m      %button{ type: "button", class: "navbar-toggle", "data-toggle" => "collapse", "data-target" => "#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" }[m
[32m+[m[32m        %span{ class: "sr-only" }[m
[32m+[m[32m          Toggle navigation[m
[32m+[m[32m        %span{ class: "icon-bar" }[m
[32m+[m[32m        %span{ class: "icon-bar" }[m
[32m+[m[32m        %span{ class: "icon-bar" }[m
[32m+[m[32m      %a{ href: "/blog" }Blog home[m
[32m+[m
 [m
 #blog-content[m
   %h1 <redacted>[m
```

Note: in Sublime, most lines have one or more `[ESC]` characters that aren't appearing in SO.

I could find nothing strange about the commands I entered around this time (e.g. no noticeable typos). Also, this was over ssh, if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

Check your command history. Most likely, you had local changes and did something like:

```
git diff HEAD > s
```

This could have happened sometime in the past, which might explain why you don't see if in your recent history.